Connectivity mechanism from Azure Synapse to AWS PostGres for data replication
How to Connect to PostGres from Azure Synapse. I tried from Linked Services but getting errors.
I tried connecting it from Linked Services, Is it the right way to do it ? or we can connect through other mechanism from Synapse. I do have DB details/Password/Host name for PostGres which I connect from PG Admin.

AFAIK, there is no direct way to connect Azure Synapse to AWS PostGres through linked service.

There is not a direct built in connector to connect AWS Postgres in azure synapse pipeline. so, you can connect AWS Postgres with Npgsql driver and a self-hosted integration runtime (SHIR)
You need to connect it using ODBC driver connector and linked service
here are steps to create ODBC data source:

Install ODBC driver and Run as Administrator
Open the  System DSN  tab and click Add:
Choose the latest PostgreSQL ODBC driver and click Finish:
Enter the ODBC credentials like username, password, hostname etc.
Test the data source connection:
Click  Save  to create the ODBC data source

After this create linked service for this ODBC data source in azure Synapse to connect AWS Postgres
Also check this similar SO thread answer by @Jason Horner
